# drools package name (Fluent api)

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I am trying to create rules in java by using the [Fluent Api](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/droolsjbpm-introduction-docs/html/ch02.html#d0e124). Actually I have successfully created rules in a way I like, however I could not find a way to create a rule without adding a package name.

Java Code:

```
PackageDescr pkg = DescrFactory.newPackage()
   .name("org.drools.example")
   .newRule().name("Xyz")
       .attribute("ruleflow-grou","bla")
   .lhs()
       .and()
           .pattern("Foo").id( "$foo", false ).constraint("bar==baz").constraint("x>y").end()
           .not().pattern("Bar").constraint("a+b==c").end().end()
       .end()
   .end()
   .rhs( "System.out.println();" ).end()
   .getDescr();

DrlDumper dumper = new DrlDumper();
String drl       = dumper.dump(pkg);
```

DRL File:

```
package org.drools.example  ---> I do not want this to be included

rule "Xyz"
    ruleflow-grou bla
when
    (
    $foo : Foo( bar==baz, x>y )  and
    not( 
    Bar( a+b==c )   ) ) 
then
System.out.println();
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using Drools 7.3.0 which was installed default by eclipse

Comment: But what's the problem? You want your rules to have different package names?

Comment: I'm running my java code to generate more than 10-15 rules at different times for the same package, It just looks dirty in the drl file to see the same package name for each rule over and over again. I do not know what is the best practice but I generally add package names to the start of the file. @EstebanAliverti

Comment: I see, could you include a code snippet on how are you using the fluent API? Are you invoking DescrFactory.newPackage() for each of the rules you want to generate? How are you getting the DRL from the package that gets built?

Comment: Yes to your question @EstebanAliverti . I am searching to find another way of creating rule rather than calling DescrFactory.newPackage() every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to reuse the same `PackageDescrBuilder` for all your rules. After you are done with one rule, just call `end().newRule()` to start with your other rule:

```
PackageDescr pkg = DescrFactory.newPackage()
  .name("org.drools.example")
    .newRule().name("Rule 1")
      .attribute("ruleflow-grou","bla")
      .lhs()
        .and()
          .pattern("Foo").id( "$foo", false).constraint("bar==baz").constraint("x>y")
          .end()
          .not().pattern("Bar").constraint("a+b==c")
          .end().end()
        .end()
      .end()
    .rhs( "System.out.println();" ).end()
    .newRule().name("Rule 2")              // <--- Here starts the new rule
      .lhs()...end()
      .rhs()...end()
.getDescr();
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Is this Fluent API safe to use? I'm trying to parse JSON and create the rules from that. Is there a better way to do it? And also, is there a documentation about this API? I could not find so much information about it on the internet. @EstebanAliverti

Comment: The API is not a public one, and thus it may be subject to changes without notice.

Comment: Can we create a rule without using the DescrFactory.newPackage(), with just using DescrBuilder or something? Because, right now my java code runs for each rule, so I cannot do the thing you proposed `.rhs( "System.out.println();" ).end()
    .newRule().name("Rule 2") 
      .lhs().end()` . Thanks @EstebanAliverti

Comment: If you are processing one rule at a time and returning the DRL, couldn't you just manually remove the "package XXX" line?

Comment: Since I was creating the rule as a String, your last comment invoked the idea that I can change the rule like the following:`drl.replace("package org.drools.example", "")` , So this solved my problem thanks @EstebanAliverti.

Comment: How can we use the Fluent API in Drools 8?